# Provider $get method is not called in jasmine unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, provider

I am using custom provider in my app.js to make backend call and then in controllers just injecting that provider and getting promise result (I make this because instead to call getLoggedUser in every controller I am just getting results from provider) and instead of making 10 calls for example I will make just one in provider). But I am unable to test this provider $get method and test is failing because backend call is never made.

I am getting error :

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET https://localhost:8443/user/current
```

**app.js**

```
 angular.module('app', [
            ...
        ])
        .config(config)
        .run(run)
        .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
        .value('version', '1.1.0')
        .provider('userProvider', function(){

            this.$get = ['AuthenticationService',
                function(AuthenticationService) {
                    return AuthenticationService.getLoggedUser();
                }];
        });
```

**TEST**

```
/* jshint undef:false*/
(function() {
    'use strict';

    describe('ListingController', function() {
        var listingController, rootScope, scope, q, mockAuthenticationService, $httpBackend, service;
        var provider = {};
        var mockCurrentUser = {
            id: 1782,
            name: "One, Coordinator",
            roleId: [
                3, 10
            ],
            eauthId: "coodinator1"
        };

        beforeEach(module('app'));
        beforeEach(module('listing'));
        beforeEach(function () {
            module(function (userProviderProvider) {
                provider = userProviderProvider;
            });
        });
        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $q, _$httpBackend_, _AuthenticationService_, userProvider, $injector) {
            rootScope = $rootScope;
            scope = rootScope.$new();
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            q = $q;
            mockAuthenticationService = _AuthenticationService_;
           // provider = userProvider;
            service = $injector.invoke(provider.$get);

            rootScope.$digest();

            listingController = $controller('ListingController', {
                $scope : scope,
                mockAuthenticationService : _AuthenticationService_
            });
        }));
        describe('getLogged user and init',function(){
            it("should call getLogged function", function() {
                listingController.getLoggedUser();

                rootScope.$digest();

                expect(service).toHaveBeenCalled();
            });
        });
    });
})();
```

**Controller**

```
function getLoggedUser() {
            userProvider.then(function (data){
               // Here I am getting result from back end call from provider     which is good
        });
```

If I make something like this in provider:

```
this.$get = function (AuthenticationService) {
                return {
                    loggedUser : function() {
                        return AuthenticationService.getLoggedUser();
                    }
                }
            }
```

I can then make something like this in test:

```
 spyOn(provider , 'loggedUser').and.callFake(function() {
                var deferred = q.defer();
                deferred.resolve(mockCurrentUser);
                return deferred.promise;
            });
```

and this will work test will pass, but with this approach in every controlle when I user userProvider.loggedUser().then it will make additional back end call and with above one only once back end call will be made.

**Update for Ceylan**

If I do like you suggest to call service and in method call getLoggedUser from another service additional calls are being made every time...not just one like I have without function.

```
.provider('userProvider', function(){
            return {
                $get: function(AuthenticationService) {
                    return new userService(AuthenticationService);
                }
            }
        });
```

**service**

```
   function userService(AuthenticationService) {
        this.getLoggedUser  = function() {
           return  AuthenticationService.getLoggedUser();
        }
    }
```

Comment: define the expected url request in $httpBackend

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş I add to it function :

it("should call getLogged function", function() {
                listingController.getLoggedUser();

                $httpBackend.expectGET('https://localhost:8443/user/current').respond(200);
                $httpBackend.flush();

            });

but again same error...

Comment: `$httpBackend.when('GET', 'localhost:8443/user/current').respond(200);
$httpBackend.expect('GET', 'localhost:8443/user/current');`

Comment: and be sure that the url is the same or use regex

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic structure:

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'localhost:8443/user/current').respond(200, /*optional response callback function*/); 
$httpBackend.expect('GET', 'localhost:8443/user/current');

//here goes the function that makes the actual http request

$httpBackend.flush();
```

Be sure that you define your httpBackend var - `var httpBackend = $httpBackend;`.

And also in order to check did the service was called, you must use spy.

```
spyOn(service, 'method').and.callThrough();

//here goes the function that calls the service

expect(service.method).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

You combine the two blocks above and you should be able to achieve what you want.

```
describe('something',function(){
            it("should do something", function() {

                spyOn(service, 'method').and.callThrough();

                $httpBackend.when('GET', 'localhost:8443/user/current').respond(200,/*optional response callback function*/); 
                $httpBackend.expect('GET', 'localhost:8443/user/current');

                //call the function that makes http request and calls your service

                rootScope.$digest();
                $httpBackend.flush();

                expect(service.method).toHaveBeenCalled();
            });
        });
```

And about your service:

```
function myService(){
    var svc = this;

    svc.myMethod = function(){
         return someDataOrPromise;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that I need to use spy.. but problem is that this provider does not have function... I don't have method so which method to add in spyOn? That is my concern..

Comment: put you functionality inside service.method and return the service.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow.. Functionality for getting logged user is in other service which returns promse.

Comment: I tried with approach with new service and calling method but as I said this will make back end call everytime when I call userProvider.myMethod().then in controllers...